# One accessor method returing a VARIANT or several returning distinct types?

Tags: com, interop

I have a COM interface and need to add an accessor method to it. The returned value can actually be of one of 4 types: VARIANT_BOOL, long, BSTR or an IDispatch derived interface.

I therefore have a choice: either I return a VARIANT or I have 4 different access methods that return distinct types.

```
interface IValue1 {
    HRESULT GetType( TypeEnum* );
    HRESULT GetValue( VARIANT* );
};
```

or

```
interface IValue2 {
    HRESULT GetType( TypeEnum* );
    HRESULT GetLongValue( long* );
    HRESULT GetBstrValue( BSTR* );
    HRESULT GetBoolValue( VARIANT_BOOL* );
    HRESULT GetInterfaceValue( ICustomInterface** );
}
```

I will have the IValueX::GetType anyway - for clarity. If I choose the latter option only one of 4 accessors will actually return value, all others will indicate an error because of type mismatch.

I need this interface being consumable from as wide range of clients as possible - VB6, Perl, .NET included.

Which alternative is better - with VARIANT or with distinct types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client programmer is going to have to query the GetType method in both alternatives followed by a switch statement. Therefore, I don't really see any advantage in multiple, type-specific methods.

However, the VARIANT approach would clearly be less confusing to the client coder. Fewer methods means lesser cognitive load. So I think you should pick it over the other.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really like either because of the `GetType` thing, but go with the first. I think it is more flexible. In the event of future changes to the code which could require it to return a type not available in the current set, the second version would require you to create a new interface, and possible changes to client code to handle the new interface.

Answer (score 1):

I like the second one. Or both, for the rare times when the consumer really doesn't care what they're given (kinda like `SqlDataReader.GetValue`). Like Frederick points out, the client coder will probably end up writing a select case statement, so you may as well code up the "proper" data types. It **really** depends what the expected usage patterns are to be, but I'd lean towards proper data types over variants.